# ¿Cómo funciona el Array.Exists?

Tags: c#

No sé bien como usar el array exist en todos los casos.

Explicación del ejercicio: se trata de un array este tiene que hacer las siguientes cosas.

1. dejar que el usuario elija cuantos espacios quiere en el array
2. recibir los numero y identificar si el usuario ha insertado un numero que ya existe
3. en caso de que el usuario inserte un numero que ya existe descartar el numero repetido dentro del array y poner un mensaje tipo:`("se ha descartado el numero antes insertado porque ya existe")`
   y que después vuelva al array para volver a insertar un número.
   código de muestra incompleto:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] name = new string[x];
            int f = 1;
            for (int t = 0; t < x; t++)
            {
                name[x] = Console.ReadLine();
                var check = Array.Exists(name, x => f == );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recordatorio: lo primero que indica el [tour] es que esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas :) Además, si quieres evitar que te _baneen_, simplemente formula preguntas teniendo en cuenta [ask].

Comment: ok bro gracias por tu observación la tendré en cuenta pero no tienes nada que aportar sobre el tema de la pregunta ??? de todos modos te agradezco por tus ediciones y observaciones

Comment: Que no entendiste de la documentacion_? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-5.0

Comment: creo que entendi + o - xd

Comment: Perfecto.. entonces aclara en la pregunta que parte no entendiste de la documentacion, y ahi podemos darte una respuesta...  Si no, solo te copiariamos la documentacion, y estamos en lo mismo de ahora....

Comment: ok ya se como hacer la sintaxis del array exist pero no se como podría hacer que el objeto dentro del array exist no sea el mismo en el tiempo de ejecución se supone que cada vez que el usuario ingrese un numero el array exist busque si ya existe en el array

Comment: Claro.. entonces no guardes el numero nuevo en el array... guardalo en una variable, buscalo en el array, y si no existe lo agregas... si existe, no lo agregas.. no deberias usar un for... deberias usar un while....

Comment: como le hago para que lo verifique                                                                                  
        
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("cuantos elementos quiere en el array :");
            string[] name = new string[x];
            int f = 1;
            int t = 0;
            while (t < x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("escriba un numero para insertar en el array: ");
                int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
                Array.Exists(name, element == h  );

Answer (score 0):

**Ejemplo simple**: buscar por elemento y por la letra

```
string[] planetas= { "Mercury", "Venus", "TIERRA", 
"Mars", "Jupiter","Saturn", "Neptune" };

Console.WriteLine("Uno o más planetas comienzan con'M': {0}",
Array.Exists(planetas, element => element.StartsWith("M")));


 Console.WriteLine("¿Es Plutón uno de los planetas? {0}",
 Array.Exists(planetas, element => element == "Saturn"));
```

¡Visita https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-5.0 para mas información!

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so], te recomiendo leer [answer], para que mejores tu respuesta dando más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Para responder ESPECÍFICAMENTE a tu pregunta (esto parece más una pregunta X->Y)

> ¿Cómo funciona el Array.Exists?

`Array.Exists<T>(T[], Predicate<T>)` es un método estático, (la clase `Array` no necesita ser instanciada para poder hacer uso del método) que retorna un valor booleano, `true` o `false`, en caso que el `Predicate` se cumpla.

El `Predicate` es un `Delegate` que retorna un valor booleano en caso que se cumpla o no se cumpla. Básicamente, podrías leerlo como *del arreglo name, para cada uno de los element, verifica que es igual al valor que te paso (el nombre dentro de name[t])*.

Tal vez esto te de una idea de como continuar:

```
string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
bool nombreExiste = Array.Exists(name, element=> element.Equals(nombre)); // si vas a comparar strings, hazlo con Equals().
if (nombreExiste) { // introducir el nombre en el arreglo.
   name[t] = nombre;
}
```

La documentación es clara. Sugiero dediques algunas horas para profundizar en lo que no comprendas en su totalidad.

Comment: gracias amigo aunque necesito una mano ya que me cuesta mucho aprender a programar ya que mi profe no le da la gana explicar solo me da links de videos en youtube podrias enseñarme o explicar mis dudas mas adelante : )

Comment: Bueno, el dicho *"No todo te lo enseñan en la universidad"*, es especialmente cierto en esta carrera. Cerca del 95% de todo lo que sé, lo he aprendido leyendo documentación, llevando cursos y durmiendo hasta las 12am todos los días. Esto te lo puede decir cualquiera en este sitio. Suerte.